# Find largest possible value of $x+y$

Tags: trigonometry

If $4\sin x. \cos y + 2\sin x+2\cos y+1=0$, find the largest possible value of the sum $(x+y)$. How do I manipulate my expression? I am not getting $(x+y)$ form. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe Lagrange multiplayer could help?

Comment: $(2\sin x+1)(2\cos y+1)=0$

Comment: Are we constraining $x,y$ to $[0,2\pi].$  Otherwise there is no bound for $x+y$ for this curve.

Comment: @Mann you should place this in the answer action. Nice.

Comment: Naa, it's ok It would be too small anyway. :)  The answer seems to be $\frac{23\pi}{6}$ where $y=2\pi$ and $x=\frac{11 \pi}{6}$ $\forall$ value of $x,y \in \left[0,2\pi\right]$

Answer (score 0):

As Shown by Mann (2sinx+1)(2cosy+1)=0
Maximum value of x+y occurs when both expressions are 0
x+y=11.$\pi$/6 + 4.$\pi$/6=15.$\pi$/6

Comment: Could you improve the formatting of your answer by using MathJaX? Maybe add a sentence or two to explain what you are doing?